# Resolving a list of components as a constructor argument

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Say I have an interface to define formatting reports:

```
public interface IFormatter 
{
    string Name {get;}
    Report Format(InputData data);
}
```

and an implementation of a provider that will format reports for me:

```
public FormatterProvider : IFormatterProvider
{
    private readonly IList<IFormatter> _formatter;

public FormatterProvider(IList<IFormatter> formatters)
{
    _formatters = formatters;
}

    public IFormatter GetFormatter(string name){ return _formatters.Where(x => x.Name == name); }
}
```

I know I can register all of the formatters in an assembly using this registration:

```
container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyName("MyCompany.Formatters")
        .BasedOn<IFormatter>()
        .WithService
        .FromInterface()
    );
```

But, how to I register the provider so that any formatters registered in the container are passed to it's constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the subresolver called CollectionResolver.

```
Container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(Container.Kernel, true));
```

I think you will need to change the IList to IEnumerable to make this work, but not for sure on that.

Comment: It looks like it works with a few different collection types: [http://docs.castleproject.org/(S(bcwix455ivqyod45twfzyj45))/Windsor.Resolvers.ashx]There are many collection types that CollectionResolver supports. Namely IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>, IList<T> and T[].

Comment: Yah, I just used it the first time the other day so when I saw your situation I figured it would work well.